# Why is ubuntu showing up in UEFI BOOT. Only OS Installed is Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, grub2

After having trouble with a dual boot SSD I decided to start over, get a fresh SSD and use just Linux Mint. However, I noticed that when I enter my boot menu it shows ubuntu and UEFI: Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB (Only Mint is installed). Does anyone know what would be causing this. When I select the Samsung SSD I get a quick message that says something like "system boot order not found initializing defaults"[image]

Comment: can you be more specific on what you mean with “this”? do you mean “ubuntu” while having mint installed or why there are two entries?

Comment: Mint is not an official flavor of Ubuntu, but uses Ubuntu as its base. It may show as Ubuntu in UEFI. With Ubuntu, any flavor, you get an Ubuntu entry at /EFI/ubuntu using /EFI/ubuntu/grub and fallback or drive entry at /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which is just a copy of shimx64.efi. The UEFI entry will use the GUID/partUUID for ESP. `efibootmgr -v` & partUUID: `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid,partuuid | egrep -v "^loop"` and then configfile to full grub in `cat /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` is UUID of your / (root) partition.

Comment: @oldfred Not going to lie. A lot of that went over my head. Are you saying that this is normal for a Linux Mint Install??

Comment: I believe so. Does the system boot and message is just a warning? Does UEFI: Samsung entry work? That is a fallback boot entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you replaced the drive and installed another distro, the actual EFI boot entries are stored in machine's NVRAM, not on the drive. Your machine's BIOS should typically enable you to remove boot entries, and there are tools for that as well. Check the same question here on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/930725/how-to-delete-os-from-boot-menu

Note that if you remove the active entry by mistake you'll probably have to boot from external media and reinstall grub.